# Including Ntddvdeo.h in Application: Causes Compile Error

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to include the Ntddvdeo library in my C++ WinAPI application but I get the error `Error: Cannot open source file Ntddvdeo.h`

**How can I include Ntddvdeo.h in my program?**

I need to include it just to use one variable, the GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MONITOR variable. Any advice on how I can include the library? Do I need to include a specific dll or lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ntddvdeo.h is a header in the windows driver kit. If all you need is the value for the GUID, you can just define it somewhere in your code yourself.

```
//
// Monitor device interface
// {E6F07B5F-EE97-4a90-B076-33F57BF4EAA7}
DEFINE_GUID(GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MONITOR, 0xe6f07b5f, 0xee97, 0x4a90, 0xb0, 0x76, 0x33, 0xf5, 0x7b, 0xf4, 0xea, 0xa7);
```

Comment: yeah thats what I ended up doing rather than fiddle around with included that header file.